# jQuery onClick GoTo ID or Class

Tags: jquery, class, click, goto

For some odd reason my Header gets all messed up when I click on an A tag to go to an ID.  So instead is there a way to use jQuery to do this, such as a Click(), Goto ID?

```
<a href="#allreviewstop">Read Reviews (1)</a>
<div style="height:1500px;"> Really Long Stuff</div>
<div id="allreviewstop"> My Reviews go down here</div>
```

This is the page I'm dealing with [Click Here](http://v725959.htrhdfbkcym2.demo6.volusion.com/product_p/war-wpm60.htm)

Comment: Where are the anchors on that page, and the links to them?

Comment: Under the Product Title where it says "Read Reviews".  Then it goes to the reviews on the bottom right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("div").click(function() {
    window.location.hash = "#"+$(this).attr("id");
}
```

Is that what you're after?

[edit] I can't remember if you need the # or not. Try it without if it doesn't work.

Comment: You might like this more, though: http://beski.wordpress.com/2009/04/21/scroll-effect-with-local-anchors-jquery/

Answer (score 2):

Try the jquery [ScrollTo](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo) plugin -

also check the [demo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/)

```
$(function(){
    $("#goTop").click(function(){
      $.scrollTo($("#nav"), { duration: 0});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this plugin helps you: [jQuery ScrollTo](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo) ?

Comment: this is a link answer that has expired

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the `window.location.hash` solution only works once. If you don't want to use the plugin you could try this:

```
var navigationFn = {
    goToSection: function(id) {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(id).offset().top
        }, 0);
    }
}
```

and then call it like so (where `someID` is the ID of the element you wish to scroll to):

```
navigationFn.goToSection('#someID');
```

With this you can also vary the animation speed (I have it at 0) so that it is instant, but you could pass the value to the function so the code is reusable.